# Junk appearing when converting to char from int32 in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, type-conversion

I am using a simple code to convert an uint32_t variable to char.

```
uint32_t len = 4 + data.length(); //data is a string
char pop1 = len & 0xff;
char pop2 = (len >> 8) & 0xff;
char pop3 = (len >> 16) & 0xff;
char pop4 = (len >> 24) & 0xff;     //also tried the same thing with memcpy

printf("%02x \n",pop1);
printf("%02x \n",pop2);
printf("%02x \n",pop3);
printf("%02x \n",pop4);
```

Output :

```
ffffff81
02
00
00
```

I fail to understand why the junk is added to the first byte. When I use `unsigned char` instead, no junk is added. In my understanding both char and unsigned char are 8-bits, then why the char is treated like a 32-bit value. I am using VS2015 on a 64 bit Windows machine. I want to use the char array for the send function of WinSock2.

```
send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, size_to_send, 0); // sendbuf is a char array
```

Comment: TL/DR: Use `unsigned` variables when doing bit manipulation. Your `char` is `signed`.

Comment: @Slava: I expect there is an original for which this is a duplicate, but that question was not it. Asking why these extra bits appear is different from asking how to avoid them, and the answers to the latter question do not answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a value of a small integer type (like `char`) is passed as an argument to a vararg function (like `printf`) it is [*promoted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to an `int`

This promotion can include *sign extension* if the small type is `signed`.

On [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) systems (which is the vast majority of computers a long time) that mean the `int` will be padded with `1` bits, which when printed as an `unsigned int` in hexadecimal will manifest as `f`.

The simple solution is to not use `char`, but preferably `uint8_t` or an explicit `unsigned char` type for your variables.

Comment: FYI, I voted for dbush’s answer over this because it more correctly and precisely describes the promotion as the conversion of the **value**. “Sign extension” is a manipulation of the **representation** of a value, and it is not what is specified by the C standard.

Answer (score 3):

When used in an expression, a `char` is first **promoted** to `int`.  So if the value of the `char` value is negative, that value is preserved when it is converted to `int`, and that is what you see when you print.

You can either cast the value to `unsigned char` to have it take on a positive value, or you can use the `hh` modifier on the `%x` format specifier to have it treat the value as an `unsigned char`.

```
printf("%02hhx \n",pop1);
printf("%02hhx \n",pop2);
printf("%02hhx \n",pop3);
printf("%02hhx \n",pop4);
```

Comment: Additionally, using `%02x` for an argument that is a `char` promoted to an `int` mismatches the type, since `%02x` requires an `unsigned int` argument.

Answer (score 3):

Think of all the type changes and conversion happening.  There are at least 4.

`0xff`, an `int` is converted to `uint32_t`, then the `&` occurs.  No problems here.

```
len & 0xff;
```

Then that result is assigned to a `char`, a *signed* `char` in OP's case. That assigns a `0x81` (129) that is out-of-range to the `char` --> *Implementation defined behavior*.  A common result simply passes the smallest bits.

```
char pop1 = len & 0xff;
```

> why the char is treated like a 32-bit value (?)

It is not treated yet as a 32-bit *unsigned* value, but as an 8-bit *signed* value.

Then code pass `char pop1` (with maybe a value of -127) to `printf();` and incurs an *default argument promotion* as an argument to the ... function.  `printf()` receives an `int` with the value of -127.

```
printf(...,pop1);
```

`printf("%02x \n",pop1);` expects an `unsigned` and not an `int`.  As the value of -127 is not representable as both an `int` and `unsigned`, (c11 §6.5.2.2 6), the conversion specifier is not valid with that argument and the result is *undefined behavior* (UB). (§7.21.6.1 9).  What typically happens is that the bit pattern of `-127` passed as an `int` is interpreted as the bit pattern for an `unsigned` and result in `"ffffff81"`.

```
printf("%02x \n",pop1);
```

---

To avoid the implementation defined behavior and the UB, recommend the below.  For effective *unsigned* code, use clearly *unsigned* types, objects and constants.

```
unsigned char pop1 = len & 0xffu;
// or
uint8_t pop1 = len & 0xffu;
```